# How to find the IP address of a website using the QDnsLookup class?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, dns

I am trying to learn network programming with the Qt library.

As exercise, I am trying to lookup the IP address of google:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtNetwork>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDnsLookup lookup(QDnsLookup::ANY, "http://www.google.com");
    lookup.lookup();
    while (!lookup.isFinished())
    {
        // Just wait.
    }
    auto records = lookup.hostAddressRecords();
    for (auto record : records)
    {
        std::cout << record.timeToLive() << "; " <<
                     record.value().toString().toStdString() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the lookup never finishes and `lookup.isFinished()` never returns true. I tried to read the documentation of [QDnsLookup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdnslookup.html), but I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QDnsLookup is asynchronous API, that depends on a Qt event loop running to update its state. So you either need to force Qt to handle events in your waiting loop:

```
while (!lookup.isFinished())
{
    QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

or you do it the more Qt-ish way and actually run the application and handle the `finished` singal of QDnsLookup (the lambda might better call a named function, but it's just an example):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDnsLookup lookup(QDnsLookup::ANY, "www.google.com");
    QObject::connect(&lookup, &QDnsLookup::finished, [&lookup]() {
        auto records = lookup.hostAddressRecords();
        for (auto record : records)
        {
            std::cout << record.timeToLive() << "; " <<
            record.value().toString().toStdString() << '\n';
        }
        QCoreApplication::quit(); // we don't want to do anything else
    });
    lookup.lookup();
    return a.exec();
}
```

(Note that you should use just `www.google.com`, since `http://www.google.com` is not a valid domain name.)